# Unable to locate element for password field of Gmail login page

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, element

I am trying to write a program for Gmail login using Selenium. I am able to hit URL, enter username and click "Next" button, but when I redirected to "Password" field page I am unable to locate that element. I tried the same using by.className. Following is the inspected code for field:

```
<input class="whsOnd zHQkBf" 
       jsname="YPqjbf"  
       autocomplete="current-password"  
       spellcheck="false"  
       tabindex="0"  
       aria-label="Enter your password"  
       name="password"  
       autocapitalize="off"  
       autocorrect="off"  
       dir="ltr"  
       data-initial-dir="ltr"  
       data-initial-value=""  
       badinput="false"  
       type="password">
```

and following is selenium code I have written:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("whsOnd zHQkBf")).sendKeys("Password");
```

I also tried using Id, by using parent `<div id ="password"....>`, but it didn't work.

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: please try my answer and let me know your feedback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [automation Gmail login using selenium webdriver in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455269/automation-gmail-login-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Please post the relevant error messages for each attempt or describe in what way the code attempt didn't work.

Comment: The error message for the `className()` attempt is going to be that you can't use compound classes. You can't use `.className()` to find more than one class and you've provided two, note the space between the class names.

Comment: I think google changed something with the way their login works recently, and it's causing this problem.  I tried using a piece of selenium code that's always worked in the past, but it's giving errors every time now, no matter what I try.  Most of the errors are either timeouts, or some variant of "Element not visible."

Answer (score 2):

`whsOnd zHQkBf` means that the element has two CSS classes `whsOnd` and `zHQkB`. So you won't find anything that has a class with the name `whsOnd zHQkBf`.

You have to instead use a CSS selector to find an element with multiple classes like this: `.whsOnd.zHQkBf`. But this matches multiple elements on the google login page. It's easier to use the following CSS selector `input[type='password']`.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("Password");
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. Please provide some other solution.

Comment: Like 2 of the other answers, I was able to get this to work by putting a 2 second sleep immediately before it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']")).sendKeys("Password");
```

Comment: This gave me the error "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not visible"

Comment: Like the answer from HaC, this is now working after I added a 2 second sleep before it.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` locator would be the simplest :

```
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Password");
```

Comment: Sorry, but none of the above is working. Please give me some other solution.

Comment: Please elaborate on what's not working - was there an error?

Comment: This was not working for me earlier.  I was going to try it to give you my error message, but it's now worked three times in a row.  The only thing I did differently this time vs. previously is I included a 2 second sleep just before this call.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("Password");
```

Comment: This just gave me a timeout exception.  It's like it finds the element, clicks it, but needs to take a second for some js to run before it fills in the password.

Comment: You might want to Javascript insert on that element.

Comment: I was able to get all the other answers to work except this one just by adding a 2 second wait before it.  Regardless, it was playing with this answer that made me realize what the problem was for me.  Maybe the OP has a different problem.

Comment: Sorry. Missed an opening bracket (opening square bracket before @id). Edited.

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.className("whsOnd zHQkBf")).sendKeys("Password");

Hi buddy,

The statement which you have written is wrong class name because its a compound class and we cannot use compound class to locate an element. The username and password fields are developed using angular-JS so when click sign in url both username and password will be downloaded but for user only username is shown so the password is hidden background

Try this code this will work for sure because i have tried already

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']/child::*[1]/child::*/child::*/child::*")).sendKeys("Password");

Hope you got answer 
Happy Testing

Comment: Don't use compound class to locate any item use single class name from your statement className should be "whsOnd" not "whsOnd zHQkBf"

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. Some time element will not be clickable so make driver to wait for some expected events to happen like clickable.

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[type=password));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")).sendKeys("your password");
```

Comment: I think there is some typo in the second line, it should be: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]"));