# Selenium Webdriver Gmail Next Button ID?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I get in "gmail.com" website when input email after press next button id for selenium web driver? Does not exist. only exists `<div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div>` this. How can I find ID of next button?

[automation Gmail login using selenium webdriver in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455269/automation-gmail-login-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java) in this link answer is id = identifierNext for next button. But how can I know it is ID?

Comment: If you `F12` on that element,  you'll get the `span` tag in DevTools. When you trace its ancestor, you'll find a `div` with `role='button'` and with an `id`. This is your required `id`.

Comment: Did any answers mentioned below solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use xpath:

```
"//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `id` attribute for the `Next` button. You can use `xpath` like `.//div[@role='button' and @id='identifierNext']`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the html tag for next button by id:

```
 driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
```