# Login through Google SSO using automated browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, single-sign-on

I am trying to automate login to my app which uses among others, google sso authentication.
However login form return error "This browser or app may not be secure.". I set my google account options to allow less secure apps but still nothing.

I browsed few topics:

- [GMail is blocking login via Automation (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602974/gmail-is-blocking-login-via-automation-selenium)
- [Selenium Google Login Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117232/selenium-google-login-block)
- [Automation Google login with python and selenium shows ""This browser or app may be not secure""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66209119/automation-google-login-with-python-and-selenium-shows-this-browser-or-app-may)

And it seems that google is blocking this way at all in favor of oauth.
People write in these topics that solutions stopped working recently

So is it currently possible, to set ChromeDriver somehow using capabalities, to be able to login through SSO?. I need a simple solution, that will run headless with other scripts on cloud (not something that would require me to manually login first on another instance as one anwser suggests).
If its not possible or extremly complicated please tell me I will not waste time on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use chrome capabilities, what you can do is set the user-data-dir to a chrome profile that has already been signed in using SSO.

You should look up how to reuse chrome profiles with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If your accounts have 2 steps verifications, google believe it's safer and allows you to get login. Then the issue will be how to handle the 2 steps verifications. Working on that :/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).