# Logging in to Google using Selenium webdriver and python

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, google-signin, python-3.10

I've been having trouble logging in with Selenium web driver as it shows that I can't log in and then test, search for the word pizza, but it doesn't go beyond the login. What I'm interested in is being able to log in.

[This is the message that appears to me, Google detects that an external driver is being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIyTQ.png)

"Couldn’t sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in."

The python code I used is this, it was used with selenium 4 and python 3.10.6 (of course I changed the email and password, but still using these or mine, it doesn't go beyond that modal)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Start a new instance of the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the Google sign-in page
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")

# Find the username element and fill it with "blabla@gmail.com"
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "identifier")
username.send_keys("blabla@gmail.com")
username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait a bit for the page to load
time.sleep(50)

# Find the password element and fill it with "asdf1234" and bang! here it
# denies me doing it with the block because Google classifies me as suspicious.
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
password.send_keys("asdf1234")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait a bit for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Go to the Google search page
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Find the search element and search for "pizza"!!
search_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
search_field.send_keys("pizza")
search_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

I've tried different strategies, such as starting in a profile or temporarily duplicating the profile file that Google has in .config/google-chrome/ and using it for this (it generates problems, I don't recommend it) and still can't log in.

Can someone explain to me how I could get it to work?

Comment: Your question is answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117232/selenium-google-login-block

Comment: For Python, you might consider using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver.