# How can i do Through Selenium: My Gmail have 2-step authentication so I want to login to my gmail using my App Password.How can i do with WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, gmail, browser-automation

```
driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName").sendKeys("gmail");

driver.findElement(By.name("txtPassword").sendKeys("App Password");

driver.fundElement(By.name("Submit").click();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail login using selenium webdriver in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455269/gmail-login-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Comment: pro tip: you can write a *summarized* title and put the rest of the information in the body to make it better to read. Dont forget review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question