# Cannot use Profile current in selenium C# ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I tried this code to create a browser with my profile:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\thieu\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3");
chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But it will show a Browser that hasn't logged into any profiles, can anyone suggest where i am going wrong thanks a lot :<

Comment: There are some similar questions in stackoverflow. Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455269/gmail-login-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java/44456085#44456085

Comment: thank for your help, I will check ^^